Multi-speed switch (1Gbps / 2.5Gbps), and packet drops
I have this unmanaged PoE switch: https://www.trendnet.com/products/affordable-2-5g-poe-switch/7-port-multi-gig-poe-switch-TPE-TG327
I use it to stream images from 1Gbps industrial PoE cameras. One thing I've noticed is if my computer has a 2.5Gbps NIC port, then this setup only works if that NIC is connected to a 2.5Gbps port on the switch. The same is true if my computer has a 1Gbps NIC port, it only works if connected to a 1Gbps port on the switch.
I've tried examining this in wireshark; since I trigger the cameras at the same time I make sure to set the speeds of the cameras such that I can trigger them all and their packets don't overflow the switch. When I trigger, and the 1Gbps NIC port is connected to the 2.5Gbps port on the switch, I see "resend" packets in wireshark.
Why is this happening? Is there any way to get this to work with any port?
More on setting industrial camera speeds: https://en.ids-imaging.com/techtipp-details/items/techtip-gev-bandwidth-ctl.html

Sounds like the switch doesn’t support auto negotiation or it’s simply disabled but what you describe is actually expected. Both the device and switch must support auto negotiation

I agree with @Ramhound, except the data sheet behind that first link states "2.5G ports are backwards compatible with 100/1000Mbps devices," despite failing to mention auto negotiation appropriately. Nonetheless, it makes no mention of the 1G ports having auto negotiation, so that might be the problem. I'd be more help, but I can't decipher "when I trigger, and the 1Gbps NIC port is connected to the 2.5Gbps port on the switch."
